# Asterisk Dial Plan - redial with 44 or 0 (UK numbers)

Tags: asterisk

Have an issue with the redial numbers.

Outgoing line is configured to the digit 0, so on the dial plan it is set to "0|." (without the quotes).

Now all missed calls from the UK, starts with 44 on the IP Phone.

If i hit redial, it refuses the connection as expected.

What do i need too add, that when it sees 44, it either replaces it back with 44 or add additional 0.

I am using Elastix for front end management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add second rule for 44., and put it on first place.

that way it will use first rule for 44XXXXX and use ur current rule for all other.

Comment: this is a moment where i say D'oh! Danke! i could have sworn i tried this first and didn't work!